# Google Cloud Vision isn't returning underscore characters

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-vision

I'm testing out [Google Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) and noticing it's replacing underscores with spaces.

Does the API provide a feature to ensure these underscores are not omitted?

Code example:

```
require "google/cloud/vision"

vision = Google::Cloud::Vision.new
image  = vision.image "example_image.png"

puts image.text
```

Here is the example_image.png that I'm using:
[image]

Which produces the output: `Tom1c TH` (no underscore).

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not, sorry